# Grails Declarative Controller Exception Handling w/Base Class

Tags: grails, inheritance, controller

I'm trying to avoid code re-use by having all of my Grails controllers inherit from "BaseController". In this abstract class, I've defined a method that I want called every time the inheriting class throws such an exception (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#controllerExceptionHandling for why this should happen):

```
import com.mypackage.core.BadRequestException

abstract class BaseController {

    def badRequestException(BadRequestException e) {
        render status: 400, text: e.getMessage()
    }
}
```

Then, in my inherited class I do the following from a controller action method:

```
def changePassword() {
    ..
    if (!password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Password and password confirm did not match.")
    }
    ..
}
```

Why won't the badRequestException method of the super class get called? If I move that method to the inheriting controller (i.e., the one throwing the exception) itself it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work, but you shouldn't be trying. Use exceptions for _exceptional_ cases; mistyping a password is a common mistake. In addition to being logically inappropriate, it's also needlessly expensive; you throw an exception and cause its stacktrace to be filled in, but you're not using it, only the message. This is wasteful in general but way more so in Groovy because you have ~3x or more stack frames because of all of the extra Groovy layers. One exception isn't problematic, but needlessly incurring this small cost repeatedly will affect scalability and performance.

Comment: OK, can you suggest a better way to inform the calling API that there was an error?

Comment: How about `render status: 400, text: 'Password and password confirm did not match.'` ?